# How to pass function name of child class as parameter to parent class method in python?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def storeResult(self, function_name, result, executed_time= None):
        pass  # store result in nested dictinary



class Derived(Base):

    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def sum(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        result = a + b
        super(Base, self).storeResult("sum", result, str(datetime.now())) # Don't want to pass string,Is there any pythonic way of passing function name

    def diff(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        result = a - b
        super(Base, self).storeResult("diff", result, str(datetime.now())) # Don't want to pass string, Is there any pythonic way of passing function name

    def multiply(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        result = a * b
        super(Base, self).storeResult("multiply", result, str(datetime.now())) # Don't want to pass string, Is there any pythonic way of passing function name

    def divide(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        result = a / b
        super(Base, self).storeResult("divide", result, str(datetime.now())) # Don't want to pass string,  Is there any pythonic way of passing function name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Derived()
    d.sum(1,2)
    d.diff(2,1)
    d.multiply(1,2)
    d.divide(10,5)
    d.sum(1,12)
    d.diff(12,1)
    d.multiply(11,2)
    d.divide(10,15)
    d.sum(11,12)
    d.diff(12,1)
    d.multiply(11,2)
    d.divide(110,5)
```

I am facing following problem:

1) I want to call parent class method from child class:
line 79, in sum :: super(Base, self).storeResult("sum", result, str(datetime.now()))
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'storeResult'

2) How do you to pass function name of child class as parameter to parent class method in pythonic way?

3) I want to make sure after each function call from derived class, store each result and name of function and time of exectuted in Base class storeResult in nested dictionary like { function:{result:time}} .

I bit new to python, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *decorator* function that will wrap called methods.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps


def store_result(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.storeResult(method.__name__, result, str(datetime.now()))
        return result

    return wrapped


class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = defaultdict(dict)

    def storeResult(self, function_name, result, executed_time= None):
        self.results[function_name][result] = executed_time


class Derived(Base):
    @store_result
    def sum(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        return a + b

    @store_result
    def diff(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        return a - b

    @store_result
    def multiply(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        return a * b

    @store_result
    def divide(self, a, b):
        print 'In derived!'
        a = 0
        b = 0
        return a / b
```

I've used `defaultdict` for storing the results - it allows passing a factory function for missing keys when assigning values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply!! could you please tell me after each  function call from derived class, store each result and name of function and time of exectuted in Base class storeResult in nested dictionary like { function:{result:time}} . I'm new to python. please help on this

Comment: The wrapped method already calls `storeResult` with proper arguments. All you need to do is create a dict in your `__init__` method of `Base` class so that all instances of it have separate dict. Then, in `storeResult` just assign correct values to that dict.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer, it little challenging for beginner to understand.

Comment: That's great!! I have two elementary question  I have Base class and child class is different file. store_result(method): is this function in base class or child class file? and  If I do this  d = Derived() d.sum(1,2)    d.diff(2,1), it automatically wrap to parent class? Thanks in advance

Comment: You decorate methods where you define them. Decorating is basically syntax sugar for `method_name = store_result(method)`. If you decorate a method in `Base`, and don't override it in `Derived`, then when calling that method from inside `Derived` will call that decorated method. No magic here.